# Default values displaying as bold VB property grid

Tags: vb.net, default-value

When you do a property grid in VB and assign a value to a field, other than the default, it shows it as bold.  However, I'm having a value display as bold even though I set it to the default value.  Any one know what is causing this?  It seems to always occur when I used a double data type.  Here's my code.  I have the property definition and my constructor that constructs the class instance.  Thanks.

```
Private _FisheyeAngle As Double
    <DataMember()>
    <DisplayName("Fisheye Angle")>
    <Description("This value indicates the angle used in the fisheye view, if it is enabled.  The acceptable range is 45 to 360 degrees with 180 degrees being the default. ")>
    <DefaultValue(180)>
    Public Property FisheyeAngle As Double
        Get
            Return _FisheyeAngle
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            If value < 45 Then
                _FisheyeAngle = 45
            ElseIf value > 360 Then
                _FisheyeAngle = 360
            Else
                _FisheyeAngle = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub Initialize()


        Width = 800
        Height = 600
        FisheyeAngle = 180
        ToneCompressionRate = 1

    End Sub
```

Comment: are you asking about a propertygrid control on a form at runtime or in the IDE property editor?

Comment: Property grid control on a form.

Comment: is this part of a class?  because `Private Sub Initialize()` is **not** a constructor

Comment: Yep it's a class.  My New() constructor just calls Initialize().  Don't see why that's important.